# 18.04 fresh installation: screen goes black

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I am quite new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. Did a fresh install of 18.04. The screen goes black in some point, then video signal disappears. Already happened twice within two hours. Don't know from where to start, so I post the error log here. Maybe someone can point out, where the problem lies.

Error log:

01:13:10 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

01:13:00 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

01:12:40 kernel: ipmi_si ipmi_si.0: Interface detection failed

01:12:40 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.0: CORB reset timeout#1, CORBRP = 0

01:12:39 kernel: ttm: exports duplicate symbol ttm_agp_tt_create (owned by amdttm)

01:12:39 kernel: ipmi_si dmi-ipmi-si.0: Could not set up I/O space

01:12:39 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71

01:12:39 kernel: ttm: exports duplicate symbol ttm_agp_tt_create (owned by amdttm)

01:12:39 kernel: APEI: Can not request [mem 0xcff7d550-0xcff7d5a3] for APEI BERT registers

01:12:39 kernel: ERST: Failed to get Error Log Address Range.